# Unable to pass multiple values in not like clause Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-query-builder

I am working on a Laravel project and want to post multiple values in a not like clause. I have tried the following way with no success.

```
    $exclude_emails=['odz', 'test.com'];

    $vendors=\DB::table("vendor_infos")
              ->where("vendor_infos.email", 'not like', '%'.$exclude_emails.'%' )
              ->orderByRaw("RAND()")->take(8)->get(['vendor_infos.*']);
```

I have also tried to pass it as string, but still no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this way,

```
$query = DB::table("vendor_infos");
foreach($exclude_email as $v){
 $query->where("vendor_infos.email",'not like','%'.$v.'%');
}
$vendors = $query->orderByRaw("RAND()")->take(8)->get(['vendor_infos.*']);
```

I hope this will work

**EDIT**

Or you can try other way.

```
$exclude_emails = [
 ['vendor_infos.email' ,'not like','%'.'odz'.'%'],
 ['vendor_infos.email' ,'not like','%'.'test.com'.'%'],
];
 $vendors=\DB::table("vendor_infos")
              ->where($exclude_emails)
              ->orderByRaw("RAND()")->take(8)->get(['vendor_infos.*']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not using custom query!

```
 $exclude_emails=['%odz%', '%test.com%'];
 $exclude_emails = implode('|', $exclude_emails);
 SELECT * FROM  `vendor_infos` WHERE `email` NOT REGEXP '{$exclude_emails}' . . .
```

Easy and no matter what is the size of `$exclude_emails`.

**Laravel Way:**

If you insist to do that with laravel, you can do this :

```
// making conditions array
foreach($exclude_emails as $e){
  $final_conditions[] = ['email', 'not like', $e];
}
```

and the query as @AmitGupta answered :

```
DB::table("vendor_infos")->where( $final_conditions)->orderByRaw("RAND()")->take(8)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use array within a string that is wrapped by apostrophe. There is already '%' character in your third parameter of where function. Why did you use again in your strings?

Try this:

```
 $vendors=\DB::table("vendor_infos")
          ->where("vendor_infos.email", 'not like', '%odz%')
          ->where("vendor_infos.email", 'not like', '%test.com%')
          ->orderByRaw("RAND()")->take(8)->get(['vendor_infos.*']);
```